# what is the meaning of the following shell option - shopt -s nullglob extglob

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

we have

```
 bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

what is the meaning of the following shell option ( in bash script )

```
shopt -s nullglob extglob
```

and what is the opposite way to cancel it?

Comment: read the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin

Comment: Or even `man bash`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You unset a shell option with `shopt -u` in `bash`.

```
shopt -u nullglob extglob
```

would unset both options.  This is explained in the `bash` manual and with `help shopt` in an interactive `bash` shell.

The specific options mentioned here are well documented in the `bash` manual, but in short they are

- `nullglob`: Filename globbing patterns that don't match any filenames are simply expanded to nothing rather than remaining unexpanded.

  ```
  $ echo my*file
  my*file
  $ shopt -s nullglob
  $ echo my*file
  ```

  (no output from that last `echo` other than a blank line)
- `extglob`: Enables extended globbing patterns, such as, for example, `!(this|that)` (which would match like `*` but not any name that is `this` or `that`).

  ```
  $ shopt -s extglob
  $ touch this that theother
  $ echo !(this|that)
  theother
  ```

  The various types of extended globbing patterns are described in the `bash` manual.