# How to move a group of files that start with the same name using a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

not sure what fails in this script:

```
files=( /home/username/file* )
#echo ${#files[@]}
if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
    mv /home/username/file* /home/username/Documents/
fi
```

if I have three 3 files, the output of `${#files[@]}` is 3. If I have 2 files it is 2. If I have 1 is 1...but if I have zero files the output is also 1... not sure why. I want to skip `mv` if no files are found... How should I fix this code?
Thanks

Comment: "if I have zero files the output is also 1... not sure why" – Investigate [`nullglob`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504591/108618).

Comment: yes...I got that nullglob is the key to solve it... anyways I found another solution without using it... instead I do `if [[ ${files} = "/home/username/file.*" ]]; then` ... because if no files are found then the same path with * is printed...

Comment: Why do the check at all? I mean, why don't you just run `mv /home/username/file* /home/username/Documents/` directly? If there are no matching files, you'll get an error which you can capture if you want to show the output, or just send stderr to dev null (`2> /dev/null`) to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `-t` "destination" option for `mv`, you get an error when you provide zero files to move:

```bash
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ mv -t subdir bbbbbbb*
mv: missing file operand
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

Comment: I also get an error without -t... the goal is to skip `mv` if no file exists

Comment: I'm suggesting you don't skip it, run it and let it fail. If you don't want to see the error message or have an error status: `mv files* /destination 2>/dev/null || true`